# What is the best way to set up a shared calendar in iCal?

Tags: ical, google-calendar, calendar

I am looking to have a shared calendar which my partner and I can access.  I have a MobileMe account and my partner has a Google account.  We both have Macs, I have an iPhone and she has a Blackberry.

I am looking for a solution where we can create a calendar that we both have access to from iCal (and maybe iPhone / Blackberry if possible) and that we can both edit.

So far however, I have not managed to get anything to work.  The logical solution seemed to be to create a Google Calendar on my partner's account and subscribe to it on my MobileMe account but I cant get any changes I make to be pushed back to the Google calendar.

Answer (score 2):

Make a Google Calendar, and sync it to iCal.

Directions are in [this Google article](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99358#ical).

Comment: The above assumes that I have a google account no a mobileme account.

Comment: You can create the calendar on your partner's Google account and subscribe to it in your iCal. That way, any changes they make are reflected on yours, and any you make are reflected on theirs.

Comment: @Nathan, this is the problem I have been having, when I subscribe to a google calendar in iCal, the changes are not being reflected on my partners calendar.... will give it another go.

Comment: If you follow the directions in that article, they promise that it will push/pull both ways. It works for me.

Comment: @Nathan, which version of iCal are you using? The instructions on the link you provided do not seem to tally with my version of iCal (snow leopard).  Will give it another go tho.

Comment: I have also got this way working with iCal on Snow Leopard (although I do not have a Mobile Me account). Myself & my partner both have Google accounts and can view/edit eachothers calendars, online, on iPhone, iCal and Android (probably meany more options too, but that's what we use).

Answer (score 0):

The way we do this is having a MobileMe Family account, and share using that. You can, as Nathan suggests, use Google - but it's more complicated (and we ended up using MobileMe because we had accounts anyway).

If you're happy sharing your password with your partner, then why not log into your mobileMe account using iCal on both computers and iPhones (but not Blackberrys). You can specify to only sync Calendars and any changes will be reflected over the air on all the computers or phones.

You'll need to add the account using the Settings app -> Mail,Contacts and Calendars on your iPhone, and the Accounts tab of iCal's preferences. I'm not sure how to create an over the air calendar sync on a BlackBerry.

Comment: The problem with this is that I dont believe that you can sync the calendars with a blackberry.  Might have to resort to a shared account tho.